# Unable to reach computer in same network

Tags: wireless-networking, ssh, home-networking, netcat

Assume two machines that connect to a wireless router (Archer C7 v2) and are part of the same LAN. Pinging machine A from machine B works, but ssh, telnet, netcat fail. Why?

### Details

#### Machine A (server running Ubuntu 14.04.5, local address 192.168.0.16)

An openssh server instance is up, listening at port 2200 and running w/o issues.

```
$netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8979          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2200            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:29754         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10555         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1023          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::2200                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

The firewall is disabled:

```
$sudo ufw status' gives
Status: inactive
```

This is the output of `iptables -S` as requested:

```
$iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i ipsec+ -p 254 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5308 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5900 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5901 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 113 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5656 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5004:5005 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5004:5005 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 20830 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20830 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5060:5062 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5060:5062 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21100 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2001 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 9 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1533 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 52311 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30000:30005 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67:68 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 67:68 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 137 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 138 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 139 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1:20 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 111 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 161:162 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 520 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6348:6349 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6345:6347 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "FIREWALL: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -p udp -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "FIREWALL: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
```

#### Machine B (client running macOS 10.12.6, local address 192.168.0.14)

Attempting to connect via **ssh** results in an "Operation timed out message":

```
$ssh user@192.168.0.16 -p 2200 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -vvv
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/jdoe/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "192.168.0.16" port 2200
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.16 [192.168.0.16] port 2200.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.16 port 2200: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.16 port 2200: Operation timed out
```

**netcat** also times out:

```
$nc -w 1 -v 192.168.0.16 -z 2200
nc: connectx to 192.168.0.16 port 2200 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out
```

But hey, **ping** (which is a different protocol) works:

```
$ping 192.168.0.16
PING 192.168.0.16 (192.168.0.16): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.16: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=97.027 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.16: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.329 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.16: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.402 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.16 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.402/34.586/97.027/44.159 ms
```

What am I missing? What's in my way?

Comment: Please post the output of `iptables -S`.

Comment: Updated the post with that info. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *have* a firewall running, since `iptables -S`'s output is about two screens long. **But**, the rules in the existing firewall are configured for `sshd` listening on tcp port 22. To make a long story short, the **wrong** way to fix this -but good for testing and learning purposes- is to simply type `sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT` and voila, you can connect with `ssh`.

Afterwards, you had better tell your firewall that `ssh` is listening on port 2200 instead of 22, and you'll be done for good. It could be that `docker` deploys its own firewall, so you could have a look in its configuration files and see if you can change from there the `sshd` port.

Comment: That worked like a charm. (`sudo iptables -R INPUT 8 -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 2200 -j ACCEPT` for reference.) Thanks!